# What is the most efficient way of counting occurrences in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large (about 12M rows) DataFrame `df`:

```
df.columns = ['word','documents','frequency']
```

The following ran in a timely fashion:

```
word_grouping = df[['word','frequency']].groupby('word')
MaxFrequency_perWord = word_grouping[['frequency']].max().reset_index()
MaxFrequency_perWord.columns = ['word','MaxFrequency']
```

However, this is taking an unexpectedly long time to run:

```
Occurrences_of_Words = word_grouping[['word']].count().reset_index()
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a better way to count occurrences in a large DataFrame?

```
df.word.describe()
```

ran pretty well, so I really did not expect this `Occurrences_of_Words` DataFrame to take very long to build.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I think `df['word'].value_counts()` should serve. By skipping the groupby machinery, you'll save some time. I'm not sure why `count` should be much slower than `max`. Both take some time to avoid missing values. (Compare with `size`.)

In any case, value_counts has been [specifically optimized](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/d1a1fa27e520c0d196981df58edb1bd5d3cc3161) to handle object type, like your words, so I doubt you'll do much better than that.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this useful for speeding up counting a specific value in a series. e.g. `df.word.value_counts()['myword']` is about twice as fast as `len(df[df.word == 'myword'])`.

Comment: What about counting over the entire DataFrame? This works for one column.

Comment: To answer my own question (figured it out):
.stack() function

Comment: @Vaidøtas Ivøška, I have been struggling how to use it. Could you give an example? What if 'myword' is not in the column? It then raises a KeyError.

Comment: @Newbielp, I did this:
df[[i for i in column_names]].astype('str').stack().value_counts().sum()
which equates to setting each selected column to str type, stacking all individual columns on top, forming basically one column and then doing the value_counts() and sum() on that one column. :)
Stack is pretty useful, it might not be the most obvious choice, but worked like a charm for my use-case :)

Comment: To add to @fantabolous' comment, use the `.get()` method if there is a possibility that zero values exist in the column.  `.get()` will return `None` in that case whereas using the bracket method will throw an error.

Comment: To limit the number of results to say "top 10" highest occurence use ```df['word'].value_counts().nlargest(10)```

Comment: How to get the counting occurrences of each column value when there is N number of column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 34):

When you want to count the frequency of categorical data in a column in pandas dataFrame use: `df['Column_Name'].value_counts()`

-[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

Answer (score 26):

Just an addition to the previous answers. Let's not forget that when dealing with real data there might be null values, so it's useful to also include those in the counting by using the option `dropna=False` ([default is `True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html))

An example:

```
>>> df['Embarked'].value_counts(dropna=False)
S      644
C      168
Q       77
NaN      2
```

Answer (score 3):

Other possible approaches to count occurrences could be to use (i) `Counter` from `collections` module, (ii) `unique` from `numpy` library and (iii) `groupby` + `size` in `pandas`.

To use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
out = pd.Series(Counter(df['word']))
```

To use `numpy.unique`:

```
import numpy as np
i, c = np.unique(df['word'], return_counts = True)
out = pd.Series(c, index = i)
```

To use `groupby` + `size`:

```
out = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['word']).groupby(level=0).size()
```

---

One very nice feature of `value_counts` that's missing in the above methods is that it sorts the counts. If having the counts sorted is absolutely necessary, then `value_counts` is the best method given its simplicity and performance (even though it still gets marginally outperformed by other methods especially for very large Series).

### Benchmarks

#### (if having the counts sorted is not important):

If we look at runtimes, it depends on the data stored in the DataFrame columns/Series.

If the Series is dtype object, then the fastest method for very large Series is `collections.Counter`, but in general `value_counts` is very competitive.

[image]

However, if it is dtype int, then the fastest method is `numpy.unique`:

[image]

Code used to produce the plots:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def creator(n, dt='obj'):
    s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2*n, size=n))
    return s.astype(str) if dt=='obj' else s
    
def plot_perfplot(datatype):
    perfplot.show(
        setup = lambda n: creator(n, datatype),
        kernels = [lambda s: s.value_counts(),
                   lambda s: pd.Series(Counter(s)),
                   lambda s: pd.Series((ic := np.unique(s, return_counts=True))[1], index = ic[0]),
                   lambda s: pd.Series(s.index, index=s).groupby(level=0).size()
                  ],
        labels = ['value_counts', 'Counter', 'np_unique', 'groupby_size'],
        n_range = [2 ** k for k in range(5, 25)],
        equality_check = lambda *x: (d:= pd.concat(x, axis=1)).eq(d[0], axis=0).all().all(),
        xlabel = '~len(s)',
        title = f'dtype {datatype}'
    )
    
plot_perfplot('obj')
plot_perfplot('int')
```