# sum occurrences of a string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to count and sum totals over a dataframe, but with a condition:

```
fruit days_old
apple 4
apple 5
orange 1
orange 5
```

I have to count with the condition that a fruit is over 3 days old. So the output I need is

2 apples and 1 orange

I thought I would have to use an apply function, but I would have to save each fruit type to a variable or something. I'm sure there's an easier way.

ps. I've been looking but I don't see a clear way to create tables here with proper spacing. The only thing that's clear is to not copy and paste with tabs!

Comment: Almost a dupe: [what is the most efficient way of counting occurrences in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076195/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-counting-occurrences-in-pandas) (missing the filter part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
res = df.loc[df['days_old'] > 3, 'fruit'].value_counts()

# apple     2
# orange    1
# Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

Using `pd.DataFrame.apply` is inadvisable as this will result in an inefficient loop.

Comment: All great answers, thanks. I knew how to count but didn't know where to put the condition. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [120]: df[df.days_old > 3]['fruit'].value_counts()
Out[120]:
apple     2
orange    1
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted in the variation party.

`pd.factorize` + `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.fruit)
pd.Series(
    np.bincount(f, df.days_old > 3).astype(int), u
)

apple     2
orange    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

The `value_counts()` methods described by @jpp and @chrisz are great. Just to post another strategy, you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df[df.days_old > 3].groupby('fruit').size()

# fruit
# apple     2
# orange    1
# dtype: int64
```