# Count the number of word occurrences from a Pandas Df in Python

Tags: python, pandas, counter

this is the sample of my Pandas data frame, containing 30,000 rows [excluding column headers]. The expression comes with two classes, mainly Sad and Happy.

```
Expression              Description
Sad                     "people are sad because they got no money."
Happy                   "people are happy because ..."
Sad                     "people are miserable because they broke up"
Happy                   "They got good money"
```

Based on the example above, I would like to count the number of frequencies, which allows me to the number of word occurrences of "Sad" and "Happy" Expression's description in a dictionary.  e.g. {sad:{people:2}, happy:{happy:1}}

This is my code:

```
 def calculate_word_frequency(lst, classes):
        #variable
        wordlist = []
        dict_output = {}
        count = 0
        term = ""

data = [lst.columns.values.tolist()] + lst.values.tolist() #to convert into a list


for i in range(1,len(data)):
    if data[i][0] == classes[0]:
        wordlist = data[i][1].lower().split(" ")

        for words in wordlist:
            wordlist.append(words)

            for word in wordlist:
              if word in dict_output:
                dict_output[wordlist] += 1
              else: 
                dict_output[wordlist] == 1
                print(dict_output)
```

Expected output would be based on the number of words appearing in each Expression respectively.

```
#Test case:
  words, freqs_per_expression = calculate_word_frequency(social_df, ["Sad", "Happy"])
  #output: 538212

print(freqs_per_class["sad"]["people"]) #output: 203
```

Because of the dataset, I often face frequent hangs and lags on my VS. Hence, I am unable to retrieve any results.  I wondered if there are any better techniques that I can utilise so that I can achieve my desired data of {word:count}.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the most efficient way of counting occurrences in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076195/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-counting-occurrences-in-pandas)

Comment: @LPython that is not what OP is asking for

Comment: @yan you can explode your rows and then do a value counts

Comment: @aws_apprentice do you mean that I should combine all my rows into one single list so that I can do a value count?

Comment: just run -wc for your words and make a dictionary.

Comment: @yan can you add how you expect your output ??

Comment: @giovanislazar Yep. I have added.

Comment: @yan you want an output like this ?   {'people': 3, 'are': 3, 'sad': 1, 'because': 3, 'they': 2, 'got': 2, 'no': 1, 'money.': 1, 'happy': 1}

Comment: Using `.values` is discouraged, and `.values.tolist()` is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve the desired results in a few steps. If you are using `pandas >= 0.25` you can use the new `explode` function otherwise this solution will achieve what you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict

exploded = df.set_index('Expression') \
             .stack() \
             .str.split(' ', expand=True) \
             .stack() \
             .reset_index() \
             .drop(['level_1', 'level_2'], axis=1) \
             .rename(columns={0: 'Word'})

print(exploded)

   Expression       Word
0         Sad     people
1         Sad        are
2         Sad        sad
3         Sad    because
4         Sad       they
...

counts = pd.DataFrame(exploded.groupby('Expression')['Word'].value_counts()) \
                              .rename(columns={'Word': 'Count'}).reset_index().to_dict('records')

d = defaultdict(dict)

for rec in counts:
    key = rec.get('Expression')
    word = rec.get('Word')
    count = rec.get('Count')
    d[key].update({word: count})

print(d)

defaultdict(dict,
            {'Happy': {'...': 1,
              'They': 1,
              'are': 1,
              'because': 1,
              'good': 1,
              'got': 1,
              'happy': 1,
              'money': 1,
              'people': 1},
             'Sad': {'are': 2,
              'because': 2,
              'broke': 1,
              'got': 1,
              'miserable': 1,
              'money.': 1,
              'no': 1,
              'people': 2,
              'sad': 1,
              'they': 2,
              'up': 1}})
```

Comment: not is more easy if just put your conditions Happy and sad in your groupby???

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar `groupby` takes index values (amongst others, but they’re all related to the index).

Answer (score -2):

Here an example ,maybe this helps complete your code :

```
from collections import Counter
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
Expression,Description
Sad,"people are sad because they got no money."
Happy,"people are happy because ..really."
Sad,"people are miserable because they broke up"
Happy,"They got good money"
"""
#read csv
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')
#Only select result where Expression = 'Sad'
dfToList=df[df['Expression']=='Sad']['Description'].tolist()
# All dict 
print(dict(Counter(" ".join(dfToList).split(" ")).items()))

words=dict(Counter(" ".join(dfToList).split(" ")).items())

for key in words:
  # Here your conditions what you want
  print(key, '->', words[key])
```

Also you can to use isin() for multiple conditions..Happy...Bad...etc :

```
dfToList=df[df['Expression'].isin(['Bad', 'Happy'])]['Description'].tolist()
```

Output :

```
{'people': 2, 'are': 2, 'sad': 1, 'because': 2, 'they': 2, 'got': 1, 'no': 1, 'money.': 1, 'miserable': 1, 'broke': 1, 'up': 1}
people -> 2
are -> 2
sad -> 1
because -> 2
they -> 2
got -> 1
no -> 1
money. -> 1
miserable -> 1
broke -> 1
up -> 1
```

Comment: you also have to count the other expression, `Happy`

Comment: @aws_apprentice in this line   dfToList=df[df['Expression']=='Sad']['Description'].tolist()  ...just change Sad by Happy

Comment: what if you have `n` number of Expressions, not very effective

Comment: @aws_apprentice ..you have any idea ?.. I hope yes

Comment: I do, I just posted my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204378/discussion-between-giovanisalazar-and-aws-apprentice).

Comment: People don’t need to have a complete solution in order to ask questions about other answers, nor do they need to know everything. The question by @aws_apprentice was perfectly fine, and is actually a crucial one.