# Calculate number of occurrence of common element in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
data_SP = pd.read_csv(path_ServicePath, sep='\t', header=None)
data_SP.columns = ["Id#SP"]
print(data_SP)

    IdSP
0   SH11
1   SH11
2   SH12
3   SH12
4   SH13
5   SH13
6   SH13
7   SH13
... ...
```

and also,

```
data_SH = pd.read_csv(path_ServiceHierarchy,sep='\t',header=None)
data_SH.columns = ["Id#SH", "ConnectionClient"]
print(data_SH)
IdSH    ConnectionClient
0   SH11    CN01207507
1   SH12    CN01207509
2   SH13    CN01207539
3   SH14    CN01207542
4   SH15    CN01207564
... ...
```

In fact, I would like to calculate the number of occurrence of `data_SH` elements, in `data_SP`. In other words, how many every single element in `data_SH.['Id#SH']` is repeated in `data_SP`
As an Instance:

```
SH11 = 2
SH12 = 2
SH13 = 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `Series.where` + `Series.isin` to filter the values in `IdSP` which are also present in `IDSH`, then use `value_counts` to count the number of occurrences:

```
data_SP['IdSP'].where(lambda x: x.isin(data_SH['IdSH'])).value_counts()
```

Alternatively you can also do `value_counts` + `reindex`:

```
data_SP['IdSP'].value_counts().reindex(data_SH['IdSH']).dropna()
```

---

```
IdSH
SH11    2.0
SH12    2.0
SH13    4.0
Name: IdSP, dtype: float6
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to count values in a column is the following:

```
data_SH.value_counts()
```

Refer also to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076195/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-counting-occurrences-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

this gives count but doesn't give the count of elements that are present in data_sh and not present in data_SP.

```
    data_SP = pd.read_csv(path_ServicePath, sep='\t', header=None)
    data_SP.columns = ["Id#SP"]
    data_SP["count"] = [1]*len(df)
    data_SP=data_SP.groupby("Id#SP").count()
```