# Pandas distinct count column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926273/how-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-group-by-object/17926436#17926436) post, I would like to get a distinct count of a value in a data frame per a grouping and create a column with the distinct count values in the data frame.
Like this:

Original data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',
            'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
     'B' : ['foo', 'fo', 'foo', 'foo',
        'bar', 'bar', 'ba', 'ba'],
     'C' : [2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2]})
df

    A       B       C
0   foo     foo     2
1   foo     fo      4
2   foo     foo     4
3   foo     foo     2
4   bar     bar     5
5   bar     bar     4
6   bar     ba      3
7   bar     ba      2
```

Method from linked post applied:

```
df=df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(lambda x: len(x.unique()))
df
```

Result per linked post method:

```
A    B  
bar  ba     2
     bar    2
foo  fo     1
     foo    2
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Desired result:

```
    A       B       C   Distinct Count of C per A and B
0   foo     foo     2             2 
1   foo     fo      4             1 
2   foo     foo     4             2 
3   foo     foo     2             2
4   bar     bar     5             2 
5   bar     bar     4             2
6   bar     ba      3             2
7   bar     ba      2             2
```

Looking at the first row, the combination of "foo" in "A" and "foo" in "B" has 2 unique values associated with it (2 and 4), resulting in a 2 in each row for that combination of values for columns A and B.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) instead of `apply` because it return column with the same size as original, I couldn't find documentation on the original [pandas site](http://pandas.pydata.org) for that, but from help:

> **transform**(func, *args, **kwargs) method of
>   pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy instance
>       Call function producing a like-indexed Series on each group and return
>       a Series with the transformed values

```
df['Distinct Count of C per A and B'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].transform(lambda x: len(x.unique()))

In [1495]: df
Out[1495]: 
     A    B  C  Distinct Count of C per A and B
0  foo  foo  2                                2
1  foo   fo  4                                1
2  foo  foo  4                                2
3  foo  foo  2                                2
4  bar  bar  5                                2
5  bar  bar  4                                2
6  bar   ba  3                                2
7  bar   ba  2                                2
```